# GitHub REST API CORS error when trying to download public repository git archive

Tags: angular, typescript, github, github-pages, github-api

I'm trying to build an Angular application hosted on my GitHub pages with a custom verified domain.
This is my code to call GitHub API and get the zip archive of a (public) repository of mine:

```js
  public getTemplate() {
    return this.http.get(
      'https://api.github.com/repos/crystal-nest/cobweb-mod-template/zipball/1.20.4',
      {
        headers: {
          'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I know the URL is correct because if I paste it in my browser the download starts.
However, when the code gets executed I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://codeload.github.com/Crystal-Nest/cobweb-mod-template/legacy.zip/refs/heads/1.20.4' (redirected from 'https://api.github.com/repos/crystal-nest/cobweb-mod-template/zipball/1.20.4') from origin 'https://crystalnest.it' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I then tried with [JSONP requests](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/using-cors-and-jsonp-to-make-cross-origin-requests?apiVersion=2022-11-28#json-p-callbacks):

```js
return this.http.jsonp('https://api.github.com/repos/crystal-nest/cobweb-mod-template/zipball/1.20.4', 'callback');
```

But this time the error I received was:

```json
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "JSONP Error",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/crystal-nest/cobweb-mod-template/zipball/1.20.4?callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for https://api.github.com/repos/crystal-nest/cobweb-mod-template/zipball/1.20.4?callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error",
    "error": {
        "message": "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.",
        "stack": "Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.\n    stacktrace omitted for the sake of brevity"
    }
}
```

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/Crystal-Nest/crystalnest.it), and [here](https://crystalnest.it/generator) there's a live example (click the download button and ignore everything else, the website is very WIP at the moment).

Side note: even if the request worked and I was able to get the file as an `'arraybuffer'` (the data I need to process the file with JSZip), it's a pain that the zip name and its root directory have a code appended at the end (that I can't understand what it is and thus I can't predict what it's going to be). Ideally, I'd like to use this URL `https://github.com/crystal-nest/cobweb-mod-template/archive/refs/heads/1.20.4.zip` because it gives me a name easy to predict and thus easy to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out on GitHub community forum [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/106849#discussioncomment-8534514), the only current way to do it is by employing a proxy.
In my case, I simply used [this free and public proxy](https://corsproxy.io/).